# Label not showing up if the text height is too large

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

I tried to display some really long text with `Label` that is inside `Scroll View` but it's not showing up.

When I put smaller font size text showed up.

Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Is it because there are to many lines? Some of the other texts have for sure more than 200 lines and they are displaying normally, but this text is even longer than them.

Using `print(text.characters.count)` I get 15884 for that text.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. Why can't you use smaller font size for the text Or make the label big enough to contain the bigger text?

Comment: Because that font is too small, you can barely read text. `Label` is inside `Scroll View` so height shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Try yourText.sizeToFit() this should give you a dynamic text height. Hope this help....

Comment: You need to use UITextView with scrolling enabled and editable/selected disabled (instead of UIScrollView & Content view & UILabel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Apple Document Of UIView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview):

> In iOS 2.x, the maximum size of a UIView object is 1024 x 1024 points. In iOS 3.0 and later, views are no longer restricted to this maximum size but are still limited by the amount of memory they consume. It is in your best interests to keep view sizes as small as possible. Regardless of which version of iOS is running, you should consider tiling any content that is significantly larger than the dimensions of the screen.

As UILabel is a subclass of UIView, it seems your text with length 15884 is too long for UILabel to process when the font is big.

I think you can do some experiments to find the acceptable font size.However,I would suggest using UITextView for such long text rather than UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure the length of the string for UILabel,you can use the following method to calculate the size of UILabel:

- (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options attributes:(nullable NSDictionary *)attributes context:(nullable NSStringDrawingContext *)context NS_AVAILABLE(10_11, 7_0);

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple lines, try setting the property `numberOfLines = 0` through code or in interface builder, this should allow it to display an infinite number of lines

Comment: I have set property `numberOfLines = 0`. Other texts are displaying normally, I only have problem with this one that is longer than the others.